# Re-using Caffe files after building it

Tags: caffe, pycaffe

I succesfully builded Caffe on `Windows` 10 by following `https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/tree/windows`.

Then, after copying `C:\Projects\caffe\python\caffe` folder to my Python site_packages folder, I can use "import caffe" in Python.

My question is that if I want to use Caffe on other computers without building Caffe from the beginning, do I just need to copy the files in `C:\Projects\caffe\python\caffe folder` to the other computers' site_packages folder?

Actually, I am not familiar with 'build' and 'compile' and I don't know what 'build' is doing during the Caffe installation.

Comment: As long as the hardware and software stack is similar to your computer (where you built caffe), you should be able to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the copy provided that the destination computer uses the same support libraries (for software linkage to your Python and Caffe) and has bit-compatible hardware (to support the binary code).

I do this regularly, within a controlled cluster.  All the nodes have the same OS configuration.  I build on one node, and then copy the entire directory to the same place on the other nodes.  Then I run multi-node applications on the result.

If you switch to a different core processor, or a different OS implementation, your attempts to use the result will likely crash.  I've tried that one, too.  :-)